# Initial Puppet setup issue - filebucket perms?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to set up an initial puppet config but struggling to get it working due to failures on my first file inside the file bucket. Everything seems fine at first glance, I'm thinking I need a second opinion just to catch the issue.
So I've defined the node in nodes.pp as follows:

```
# cat /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp
node defaultclass  {
    include baseconfig
}
node 'buildmirror.briggs.uk.to' {
    include ntp
    include packages
}
```

My filebucket resides here:

```
# cat /etc/puppet/modules/baseconfig/manifests/ntp.pp
class ntp {
file { "/etc/ntp.conf":
source => "puppet:////modules/baseconfig/ntp.conf",
        owner => root,
        group => root,
        mode => 644,
        require => Package ["ntp"]
}

#file { "/var/log/ntp":
#ensure => directory,
#owner => ntp,
#group => ntp,
#mode => 755,
#}
service { "ntpd":
require => File["/etc/ntp.conf"],
subscribe => File["/etc/ntp.conf"],
ensure => running,
enable => true,
}
}
```

and the file exists in the correct directory (I think)

```
# ls -al /etc/puppet/modules/baseconfig/files/ntp.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1862 Jul 20 15:50 /etc/puppet/modules/baseconfig/files/ntp.conf
```

The problem I have is that when I run puppetd --test I get the following errors:

```
# puppetd --test
info: Retrieving plugin
info: Caching catalog for hostname
info: Applying configuration version '1342971406'
err: /Stage[main]/Ntp/File[/etc/ntp.conf]: Could not evaluate:     Could not retrieve     information from   environment production source(s) puppet:////modules/baseconfig/ntp.conf  at         /etc/puppet/modules/baseconfig/manifests/ntp.pp:8
 notice: /Stage[main]/Ntp/Service[ntpd]: Dependency File[/etc/ntp.conf] has failures: true
 warning: /Stage[main]/Ntp/Service[ntpd]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
 notice: Finished catalog run in 0.34 seconds
```

What could be causing this? I've verified the permissions on the file in the filebucket (and even tried setting them to 777 to ensure it's not a perms issue)
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Too many slashes - try `puppet:///modules/baseconfig/ntp.conf` instead of `puppet:////modules/baseconfig/ntp.conf`.

A quick note on terminology - the filebucket is actually the mechanism that clients use to archive the old version of a file that's being replaced.  What you're using here is the simply called the "file server".